# How to find first element that is hidden by JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to show first element that is hidden by jquery. my html code is:

```
<ol>
    <li>1</li>
    <li style="display:none">2</li>
    <li style="display:none">3</li>
    <li style="display:none">4</li>
    <li style="display:none">5</li>
    <li><a class="add">Add More ...</a></li>
</ol>
```

I want to show first hidden LI, each time that "a" element was clicked.
My solution is below. but I think better way exists.

```
$("a.add").click(function(){
        var hiddens=$(":hidden",$(this).parent().parent());
        if (hiddens.length>0)
        {
            hiddens.each(function(index,el){
                if(index==0)
                {
                    $(this).slideToggle("fast");
                }
            });
        }

        if (hiddens.length==1)
        {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
```

Tanx

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just add a :first selector after you get :hidden set so you get the first element from set found by :hidden selector

```
$("a.add").click(function(){
    $(":hidden:first").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution:

```
$("a.add").click(function(){
    $(":hidden:first").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You "aether":
I found below solutions after your answer:

```
$(":hidden:eq(0)",$(this).parent().parent())
```

OR

```
$(":hidden:lt(1)",$(this).parent().parent())
```

Comment: not bad, :hidden:lt(1) and ":hidden:eq(0)" seem sufficient to find the first hidden element, the second part with ,$(this).parent().parent() is not needed =)